# Sakis 3G (auto user name and passwords)

Tags: networking, passwords, modem

i am using sakis 3g to connect to internet because most of times, my modem doesn't get detected in network manager and modem detection is very slow as compared with sakis3g.

I just downloaded the script and made it executable and created a shortcut on the desktop. This is how i run it. It is in my home folder.

I want to automate connection process and to be more friendly. Everytime i connect, it asks me to choose, APN and user name and password, APN part is all right, i want it to let me select from a list of APN because many times i need to change provider.

But User Name and passwords all are blank, for all providers. I want to enter some random user name and password, and want sakis 3g doesn't ask for them.

I know this can be done, but i don't know the process, because it is mentioned, see these screenshots.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwAiSn4XUlTBZUNoSmN1Q3JTcDA&usp=sharing

If this is not the recommended way to use script, then tell me how to install, and where to install. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2123451.html

Comment: thanks problem resolved, but i did something different , i setup device id field blank, only with quotes, i didnot use --nostorage etc, i also put usbdriver="" and usbmodem=""

Comment: NP.  Please post your solution as an answer (you are allowed to answer your own questions).

Answer (score 1):

creat a configuration file for SAKIS 3G

`sudo gedit /etc/sakis3g.conf`

Put following contents in the file

> APN="CUSTOM_APN"
>
> CUSTOM_APN="vinternet.com"
>
> APN_USER="kk"
>
> APN_PASS="kk"
>
> USBINTERFACE="0"
>
> USBDRIVER=""
>
> OTHER="USBMODEM"
>
> USBMODEM=""

Replace vinternet.com with your APN, and replace kk with whatever you want, i put USB DRIVERS empty because in case i change modem, then it will automatically load appropriate drivers(Huawei, zte, option etc)

If you change your Internet provider frequently then put # in first two lines, Sakis will automatically ask you to enter APN from the list, the main part is not to ask for username and password, which is solved.

So, putting a # disable that line. If you fully want to automate the process, just change APN, if you change provider frequently , put # infront of first two lines.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have anyone username or apn_pass then put "0" or some other string in your sakis3g.conf file . it wont ask you again and again.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another more detailed answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.